# Extending nonarchimedian absolue value over a discrete complete valuation field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am following John Milne's notes on algebraic number theory and i'm having a hard time understanding his proof of the uniqueness of the extension of an absolute value to a finite separable extension L of K.
To make things short, we end up with a ring A[b] (where A corresponds to the x lying in K with norm <= 1 and we will call p the unique maximal ideal of A) which is such that:
On one hand, the quotient A[b]/pA[b] is a local ring. 
On the other hand, A[b] has 2 prime ideals containing p.
How is that a contradiction?
Any other sketch of proof is welcome though.
Thank you for your time

Comment: The ring $A[b]/pA[b]$ is isomorphic to $k[x]/(g(x)^e)$, where $g\in k[x]$ is irreducible and $e\geq 1$. This ring is not only local, but it can't have more than 1 prime ideal. In fact, $k[x]$ is a PID so every prime ideal containing $(g(x)^e)$ must be generated by an irreducible factor of $g(x)$. On the other hand, prime ideals in $A[b]/pA[b]$ are in bijections with prime ideals of $A[b]$ containing $pA[b]$, and you get a contradiction.